# Light display manager not functioning after updates

Tags: 18.04, wine, lightdm

I am sorry if this isn't in the right format or if this question was answered before.

I have a Dell Latitude 7490 running Ubuntu 18.04 64bits.
I was trying to install `winehq` to play league of legend and I had to install a few 32 bits libraries, namely:

`libfaudio:i386`
`libsdl2-2.0-0:i386`
`libpulse0:i386`
`wine-stable-i386`
`wine-stable`
`winehq-stable`

After that, I used `snapd` to run:

`sudo snap install leagueoflegends --edge --jailmode`

`sudo snap install wine-platform-5-staging`

`sudo snap install wine-platform-runtime`

As recommended for the game install.
Ever since, restarting my computer brings me to a loop on the Ubuntu splash screen. I can get access to tty and I realised that `lightdm` is failing to start. I uninstalled all libraries and snaps, and still can't get my computer to start up and bring me to the login screen.

Any help is greatly appreciated, I'm really struggling and need access back to my computer asap.

Thanks everyone for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I read on [Snapcraft's Forum](https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/call-for-testing-leagueoflegends/7229/2) that this snap is in devmode (more information about what devmode is [here](https://snapcraft.io/docs/snap-confinement)) because of technical difficulties of the creator of the snap.

`--jailmode` makes the snap be installed in strict mode, so use `--devmode` (devmode flag) instead of `--jailmode`, as the error you should get when not setting what mode to install the snap in (running `sudo snap install leagueoflegends --edge`):

```
error: The publisher of snap "leagueoflegends" has indicated that they do not consider this
       revision to be of production quality and that it is only meant for development or testing at
       this point. As a consequence this snap will not refresh automatically and may perform
       arbitrary system changes outside of the security sandbox snaps are generally confined to,
       which may put your system at risk.

       If you understand and want to proceed repeat the command including --devmode; if instead you
       want to install the snap forcing it into strict confinement repeat the command including
       --jailmode.
```